# Find last value in column instead of every value

Tags: vba, excel

So right now I have this code to find which person is signing in and put NOW=() in column G whenever they use the user form to select their name. The only problem I am having is that if the person is on the sheet previously it replaces all of the row G entries, not just the last one. I only want it to place the now=() function in the G column of the last iteration of the technicians name in the B column.

[Visual of description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4LuC.png)

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strDay As String

    strID = techname1.Value
    strDay = ""

    Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strID, Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Do
            Application.Worksheets("SignOut").Cells(rngFound.Row, "G").Value = Now()
            Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strID, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing

    Unload Me


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the last occurrence of technicians name you do not have to loop through the column. Try below code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strID As String
    Dim strDay As String

    strID = techname1.Value
    strDay = ""

    'below line will give you the last occurrence of strID
    Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(strID, Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlWhole, , xlPrevious)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        Application.Worksheets("SignOut").Cells(rngFound.Row, "G").Value = Now()
    End If

    Set rngFound = Nothing

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Syntax of `Find` function is:

***Range_Object.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)***

Here, ***SearchDirection*** is an optional parameter that specifies the search direction while searching in the range and can take one of the follwing two values:

- xlNext --> search for the next matching value in range
- xlPrevious --> search for previous matching value in range

Of these two *xlNext* is default. When you do not mention it, *Find* uses *xlNext* and searches from top to bottom in your case where range is a column. So to get the last occurrence of string use *xlPrevious* which will search from bottom to top in a column.

Comment: While the above answer is absolutely correct you still might want to add some minimal explanations. The most significant change (as far as I can tell) in your code is the addition of `SearchDirection:=xlPrevious` (as part of the [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)). So, Excel will search row by row starting with the very last row and going up until the first occurrence of `strID` is found (which is then the last one on the list).

Comment: @Ralph - Explanation added, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Josh - Did this help?